# I don't know why the object injected by dagger2 is null in presenter

Tags: android, mvp, dagger

I don't know why loginResponseHandler of MainRankPresenter.java injected by dagger2 is null in MainRankPresenter.
I just want to inject to field for field injection.
Should I do other way instead field injection?
please, Let me know how to resolve it.

BBBApplication.java

```
public class BBBApplication extends MultiDexApplication
{
    ...
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        initAppComponent();
    }

    private void initAppComponent() {
        this.appComponent = DaggerAppComponent.builder()
            .appModule(new AppModule(this))
            .build();
    }

    public static BBBApplication get(Context ctx) {
        return (BBBApplication) ctx.getApplicationContext();
    }
    public AppComponent getAppComponent() {
        return this.appComponent;
    }
    ...
}
```

AppModule.java

```
@Module
public class AppModule {
    private BBBApplication application;

    public AppModule(BBBApplication application) {
        this.application = application;
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    public Application provideApplication() {
        return this.application;
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    public Resources provideResources() {
        return this.application.getResources();
    }

    @Provides`enter code here`
    @Singleton
    public SharedPreferences provideSharedPreferences() {
        return PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this.application);
    }
}
```

AppComponent.java

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = {AppModule.class, ServiceModule.class})
public interface AppComponent {
    RankFragmentComponent plus(RankFragmentModule module);

    Application application();
    Resources resources();
}
```

RankFragmentModule.java

```
@Module
public class RankFragmentModule {

    private RankFragment rankFragment;

    public RankFragmentModule(RankFragment rankFragment) {
        this.rankFragment = rankFragment;
    }

    @Provides
    @ActivityScope
    public LoginResponseHandler provideLoginResponseHandler() {
        return new LoginResponseHandler(this.rankFragment);
    }

    @Provides
    @ActivityScope
//    @Named("rankFragment")
    public RankFragment provideRankFragment() {
        return this.rankFragment;
    }

    @Provides
    @ActivityScope
    public MainRankPresenter provideMainRankPresenter(RankFragment rankFragment) {
        return new MainRankPresenter(new MainRankViewOps(rankFragment));
    }

}
```

RankFragmentComponent.java

```
@ActivityScope
@Subcomponent(modules = {RankFragmentModule.class})
public interface RankFragmentComponent {
    void inject(RankFragment rankFragment);
}
```

RankFragment.java

```
public class RankFragment extends Fragment {

    @Inject
    MainRankPresenter presenter;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        BBBApplication.get(getContext())
                .getAppComponent()
                .plus(new RankFragmentModule(this))
                .inject(this);
        presenter.test();
    }
```

MainRankPresenter.java

```
public class MainRankPresenter implements Presenter {

    private MainRankViewOps viewOps;

    @Inject
    LoginResponseHandler loginResponseHandler;

    @Inject
    public MainRankPresenter(MainRankViewOps viewOps) {
        this.viewOps = viewOps;
    }

    @Override
    public void test() {
        Log.d(Constants.TAG_DEBUG, "=== presenter test" + this.toString());
        Log.d(Constants.TAG_DEBUG, "=== " + loginResponseHandler.toString());
        this.viewOps.initViewOps();
    }
}
```

MainRankViewOps.java

```
public class MainRankViewOps implements ViewOps {

    RankFragment fragment;

    @Inject
    public MainRankViewOps(RankFragment fragment) {
        this.fragment = fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void initViewOps() {
        Log.d(Constants.TAG_DEBUG, "=== view ops" + this.toString());
        Log.d(Constants.TAG_DEBUG, "=== " + fragment.toString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Injection by Dagger 2 is not recursive. Therefore, when you call `inject(this)` in `RankFragment` only `@Inject` annotated fields of that fragment are being injected. Dagger 2 will not search for `@Inject` annotations in the injected objects.

In general, you should attempt to restrict usage of Dependency Injection frameworks to "top-level" components (Activities, Fragments, Services, etc.) which are being instantiated by Android framework for you. In objects that you instantiate yourself (like `MainRankPresenter`) you should use other DI techniques which do not involve external framework (e.g. dependency injection into constructor).

Comment: thank you for your help. I solved it that I added this.viewOps.fragment.getRankFragmentComponent().inject(this); to MainRankPresenter constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Because you `@Provides` the `MainRankPresenter`, Dagger won't inject it: you take responsibility for this. You could possibly have your provides method be passed a `MembersInjector` si you can inject the fields if the object before returning it, but it'd probably be better to refactor your module you remove that provides method and let Dagger handle the injection (you have all the `@Inject` needed already)